# how to retain remote permissions of rsynced files

Tags: synchronization, rsync, permissions

I've read through the man page of rsync but still can't figure out what are the flags for this requirement:

- set 775 permission of new files/directories in destination host

note: local host is windows xp, remote is linux

---

edit:
i'm using the following flags for the moment.

```
-rltzC --force --delete
```

Comment: @Anand, rsync throws invalid argument passed to chmod flag :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i found it...

thanks to [http://catcode.com](http://catcode.com/teachmod/try_1.html)

rsync's chmod flag do not accept bitmask, instead it accepts `who=permissions` format.

For my question, the answer is

```
--chmod=og=rx
```

rsync will now set permission 755 for newly synced files/directories in remote host